# How to add items to a System.Collections.Generic.List object using PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have an object that has a `List<String>` as a member.  I tried adding items to this list in the following way:

```
$myObject.MyList.Add("News")
$myObject.MyList.Add("FAQ")
$myObject.MyList.Add("Events")
```

But when I check:

```
$myObject.MyList.Count
```

It returns 0.  Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Snippit from my source code:

```
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(false)]
    public List<String> SelectedTabs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$myObject.MyList` is definitely a List and not null etc. and that it is implimented such that it gives the same list each time it's accessed.  Not for example:
`public MyList {get{return new List<string>();}}//Always returns a new list`

Comment: That smells like a sharepoint webpart - there's something else going on here, probably to do with the serialization of the property value. What's your context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$source =@"
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class MyClass {
    public List<string> MyList;
    public MyClass(){
    MyList = new List<string>();
    }
}

"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharpVersion3

$myObject = new-object MyClass

$myObject.MyList.Add("test");

$myObject.MyList.Count
```

Comment: Would it make a difference that I am using `[reflection.assembly]::Load("MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13da1371f01433e6e")` instead of `Add-Type`?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - It shouldn't. Do you have sample code for you assembly?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a developer but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
PS> $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
PS> $list.Add("News")
PS> $list.Add("FAQ")
PS> $list.Add("Events")
PS> $list
News
FAQ
Events    

PS> $list.Count
3
```